# Как получить id3 информацию mp3 файла?

Tags: php

У меня подключен этот файл для сбора id3. Как из этого файла получить `title` и `artist` трека?

```js
<?php
class id3v2{
var $TargetSrcFile;
var $TargetNamFile;
var $mpegInfo;
var $id3v2Info;
var $conf;
var $jumps=3;

var $Codes=array();     //  defined in arrays.php
var $Tipus=array();     //  "   "       
var $FX=array();        //  "   "       
var $LookGenre=array();     //  "   "
var $HexPictureType=array();    //  "   "
var $LookHeaderFlags=array();   //  "   "
var $Emphasis=array();      //  "   "
var $ChannelMode=array();   //  "   "
var $Intensity=array();     //  "   "
var $LookAudioVersion=array();  //  "   "
var $LookLayerDescrip=array();  //  "   "
var $LookBitrateValues=array(); //  "   "
var $LookBitrateIndex=array();  //  "   "
var $LookFrameLen=array();  //  "   "
    
    function id3v2(){
    include("arrays.php");
    }

    function OpenFile($src){
        $this->TargetNamFile=$src;
        $this->TargetSrcFile=false;
        $this->mpegInfo=array();
        $this->id3v2Info=array();
        $this->id3v1Info=array();
        $this->conf=array();
        $this->TargetSrcFile = @fopen($this->TargetNamFile, 'rb');
        $FileSize=0;
        if ($this->TargetSrcFile) $FileSize=filesize($this->TargetNamFile);
        if ($FileSize<(100*1024)){
        return false;
        }
        else{
        $this->conf['FileSize']=$FileSize;
        $this->conf['DecodeTime']=$this->myMicrotime();
        return true;
        }
    }

    function CloseFile(){
        $this->conf['DecodeTime']=$this->myMicrotime()-$this->conf['DecodeTime'];
        fclose($this->TargetSrcFile);
    }

    function myBigEndian2IntSyn($byteword) {
        $intvalue = 0;
        $bytewordlen = strlen($byteword);
        for ($i=0;$i<$bytewordlen;$i++) {
        $intvalue = $intvalue | ((ord($byteword{$i})) & bindec('01111111')) << (($bytewordlen - 1 - $i) * 7);
        }
        return $intvalue;
    }
    
    function myHex2IntSyn($hex){
    $int = base_convert($hex, 16, 10);
    $int1 = floor($int/256) * 128 + ($int%256);
    $int2 = floor($int1/32768) * 16384 + ($int1%32768);
    $int = floor($int2/4194304) * 2097152 + ($int2%4194304);
    return $int;
    }
    

    function myBigEndian2Int($byteword) {
        $intvalue = 0;
        $bytewordlen = strlen($byteword);
        for ($i=0;$i<$bytewordlen;$i++) {
        $intvalue += ord($byteword{$i}) * pow(256, ($bytewordlen - 1 - $i));
        }
    return $intvalue;
    }

    function myStrBin2Bin($byteword) {
        $binvalue = "";
        $bytewordlen = strlen($byteword);
        for ($i=0;$i<$bytewordlen;$i++) {
            $binvalue .= str_pad(decbin(ord(substr($byteword, $i, 1))), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return $binvalue;
    }
    
    function myPrint($thisvar,$color){
        echo '<pre style="color:'.$color.'">';
        print_r($thisvar);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    function myMicrotime() {
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime()); 
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec); 
    }

    function GetGenre($genreid) {
        if ($genreid == 'RX'){
        return 'Remix';
        }
        elseif($genreid == 'CR'){
        return 'Cover';
        }
        else{
        $genreid = (int)$genreid;
        }
        $thatgenreid=(isset($this->LookGenre[$genreid]) ? $this->LookGenre[$genreid] : $genreid);
        if ($thatgenreid>147)  $thatgenreid='Unknown';
        return $thatgenreid;
    }

    function myPutKeys($KeysA,$oldArray){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($KeysA);$i++){
        $newArray[$KeysA[$i]]=$oldArray[$i];
        }
    return $newArray;
    }

    function ExtractInfo($Class,$SubClass,$Content){
    switch ($Class){
        case '2':
        $val = unpack ("A1Encoding/a*Value", $Content);
        break;
        case '3':
        $valA = unpack ("A1Encoding/a*Value", $Content);
        $valB = $this->myPutKeys(array("Description","Value"),explode(chr(0),$valA['Value']));
        $val=array_merge($valA,$valB);
        break;
        case '4':
        $val['Value'] = $Content;
        break;
        case '0':
        $val['Value'] = $Content;
        break;
        case '5':  
        $valA = unpack ("A1Encoding/a3Lang/a*Value", $Content);
        $valB = $this->myPutKeys(array("Description","Value"),explode(chr(0),$valA['Value']));
        $val=array_merge($valA,$valB);
        break;
        case '13':  
        $val = unpack ("A1Encoding/a3Lang/a*Value", $Content);
        break;
        case '8':
        $val['Encoding']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['MIMEtype']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Filename']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Description']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        break;
        case '7':
        $val['Encoding']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['MIMEtype']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $val['Picturetype']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Description']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        break;
        case '12':
        $val['Encoding']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $val['ImageFormat']=substr($Content,1,3);
        $val['Picturetype']=substr($Content,4,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,5);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Description']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        break;
        case '1':
        $val = $this->myPutKeys(array("Owner","Value"),explode(chr(0),$Content));
        break;
        case '10':
        $tempCont=strtolower(substr($Content,0,12));
        $pos=strpos($tempCont,"http");
        if ($pos===false) $pos=strpos($tempCont,"mail");
        $val['FrameId']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['URL']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        break;
        case '9':
        if ($Subclass=='2'){
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Email']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $val['Rating']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,1);
        }
        else{
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,0);
        }
        break;
        case '11':
        $val['Encoding']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Price']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        if ($SubClass=='2'){
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['ValidAndUrl']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $val['ReceivedAs']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $Content=substr($Content,1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['seller']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $pos=strpos($Content,chr(0));
        $val['Description']=substr($Content,0,$pos);
        $Content=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        $val['MIME type']=substr($Content,0,1);
        $val['Value']=substr($Content,1);
        }
        else{
        $val['DateAndSeller']=substr($Content,$pos+1);
        }
        break;
        default:
        $val['Value']=$Content;
        break;
        }
    return $val;
    }

    function GoodFrame($namelen,$FrameId,$str){
    $FrameId=strrev($FrameId);
        for ($i=0;$i<strlen($FrameId);$i++){
        $ordX=ord(substr($FrameId,$i,1));
            if ($i>0){
                if ($ordX<65 || $ordX>90){  //only [A-Z]
                return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                if (($ordX<48 || $ordX>90) || ($ordX>57 && $ordX<65)){ //[A-Z] and numbers
                return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return true;
    }
    
    function MpegGoodHeader($tempHeader){
        $Byte1=ord(substr($tempHeader,0,1));
        $Byte2=ord(substr($tempHeader,1,1));
        $Byte3=ord(substr($tempHeader,2,1));
            if ($Byte1==255 && $Byte2>223 && $Byte3<240){
            return true;
            }
            else{
            return false;
            }
    }
    
    function ProcesId3v2(){
        rewind($this->TargetSrcFile);
        $this->conf['Id3v2HeaderPos']=0;
        $this->conf['Id3v2FramesPos']=0;
        $Id3Header = fread ($this->TargetSrcFile, 10);
        $val = unpack ("a3FileIdentifier/C1MayorVersion/C1MinorVersion/a1Flags/H8TagLen", $Id3Header);
            if ($val['FileIdentifier']=="ID3"){
            $this->conf['FileIdentifier']="WithID3v2";
                if ($val['MayorVersion']<=2){
                $this->conf['MajorVersion']=2;
                $this->conf['FrameNameLen']=3;
                $this->conf['FrameFlagLen']=0;
                $this->conf['PaddingBreakStr']=chr(0).chr(0).chr(0);
                }
                else{
                $this->conf['MajorVersion']=4;
                $this->conf['FrameNameLen']=4;
                $this->conf['FrameFlagLen']=2;
                $this->conf['PaddingBreakStr']=chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0);
                    if ($val['MayorVersion']>4){
                    $this->conf['BiggerMajorVersion']=$this->conf['MajorVersion'];
                    }
                }
            $this->conf['MinorVersion']=$val['MinorVersion'];
            $StrFlags=$this->myStrBin2Bin($val['Flags']);
            $this->conf['HasSynchro']   = $this->LookHeaderFlags[$this->conf['MajorVersion']]['HasSynchro'][substr($StrFlags,0,1)];
            $this->conf['HasExtHeader'] = $this->LookHeaderFlags[$this->conf['MajorVersion']]['HasExtHeader'][substr($StrFlags,1,1)];
            $this->conf['Experimental'] = $this->LookHeaderFlags[$this->conf['MajorVersion']]['Experimental'][substr($StrFlags,2,1)];
            $this->conf['HasFooter']    = $this->LookHeaderFlags[$this->conf['MajorVersion']]['HasFooter'][substr($StrFlags,3,1)];
            $this->conf['FramesLen']=$this->myHex2IntSyn($val['TagLen']);
                if ($this->conf['FramesLen']>=$this->conf['FileSize']){
                $this->conf['FramesLen']=0;
                $this->conf['OffpaddingBreak']=0;
                $this->conf['FileIdentifier']='BadId3';
                }
                else{
                $this->conf['Id3v2FramesPos']=10;
                }
            }
            else{
            $this->conf['FramesLen']=0;
            $this->conf['OffpaddingBreak']=0;
            $this->conf['FileIdentifier']="NoID3v2";
            }
    
    
        if($this->conf['FileIdentifier']=='WithID3v2'){
        fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['Id3v2FramesPos']);
        $framedata=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['FramesLen']);
        $i=0;
        $Xoffset=0;
        $XoffsetAcu=0;
        $ready=false;
        $modified=false;
        $FrameDataLen=$this->conf['FramesLen'];
            while(($FrameDataLen-$XoffsetAcu)>$this->conf['FrameNameLen']){
            $TempTagLen=$FrameDataLen-$XoffsetAcu;
            $PrevFrameId=$FrameId;
            $FrameId=substr($framedata, 0, $this->conf['FrameNameLen']);
            if ($FrameId==$this->conf['PaddingBreakStr']){
            break;
            }
            elseif (strpos(strtolower($FrameId),"mp3")!==false){
            break;
            }
            else{
            $num=0;
                if ($this->GoodFrame($this->conf['FrameNameLen'],$FrameId,"ini")==false){
                $ready=false;
                    if ($modified==false && $this->conf['FrameNameLen']==4 && $this->GoodFrame(3,substr($FrameId,0,3),"v3")==true){
                        $XtempSize=$this->myBigEndian2Int(substr($framedata,3, 3));
                        if ($XtempSize<=$TempTagLen){
                        $FrameId=substr($FrameId,0,3);
                        $this->conf['MajorVersionAlt']=2;
                        $this->conf['FrameNameLen']=3;
                        $this->conf['FrameFlagLen']=0;
                        $this->conf['PaddingBreakStr']=chr(0).chr(0).chr(0);
                        $tempSize=$XtempSize;
                        $ready=true;
                        }
                    $modified=true; //solo una vez
                    }
                }
                else{
                $ready=true;
                $tempSize=$this->myBigEndian2Int(substr($framedata,$this->conf['FrameNameLen'], $this->conf['FrameNameLen']));
                    if ($tempSize>$TempTagLen){
                    $ready=false;
                    }
                }
                if ($ready==false){
                $num=0;
                $notappend=false;
                    while($ready==false){
                    $FrameId=substr($framedata, $num, $this->conf['FrameNameLen']);
                        if ($this->GoodFrame($this->conf['FrameNameLen'],$FrameId,"error")==true){
                            $tempSize=$this->myBigEndian2Int(substr($framedata,$num+$this->conf['FrameNameLen'], $this->conf['FrameNameLen']));
                            if ($tempSize<=$TempTagLen){
                            $ready=true;
                            break;
                            }
                        }
                    if (($TempTagLen-$num)<=0){
                    $notappend=true;
                    $ready=true;
                    break;
                    }
                    $num++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($notappend==false){
                if ($num>0){
                $previndex=count($this->id3v2Info[$PrevFrameId]['info'])-1;
                $this->id3v2Info[$PrevFrameId]['info'][$previndex]['adddata']=$num;
                $this->id3v2Info[$PrevFrameId]['info'][$previndex]['Value'].=substr($framedata,0,$num);
                }
            $inipos=$this->conf['FrameNameLen']*2;
            $Flags=substr($framedata, $inipos, $this->conf['FrameFlagLen']);
            $index=count($this->id3v2Info[$FrameId]['info']);
            $inipos+=$this->conf['FrameFlagLen'];
            $Content=substr($framedata,$inipos,$tempSize);
            $SyncData=0;
            if ($this->conf['HasSynchro']==2){
            $SyncData=substr_count($Content,chr(255).chr(0));
            if ($SyncData>0){
            $inipos+=$tempSize;
            $Content.=substr($inipos,$SyncData);
            }
            }
            $this->id3v2Info[$FrameId]['LongName']=isset($this->FX[$FrameId]['LongName']) ? $this->FX[$FrameId]['LongName'] : 'unkwonw';
            $this->id3v2Info[$FrameId]['info'][$index]=$this->ExtractInfo($this->FX[$FrameId]['Class'],$this->FX[$FrameId]['SubClass'],$Content);
            $this->id3v2Info[$FrameId]['info'][$index]['Size']=$tempSize;
            if ($SyncData>0){
            $this->id3v2Info[$FrameId]['info'][$index]['SyncData']=$SyncData;
            }
            }
            else{
            //echo "fallo en id3";
            }
            
            $Xoffset=($this->conf['FrameNameLen']*2)+$this->conf['FrameFlagLen']+$tempSize+$num+$SyncData;
            $XoffsetAcu+=$Xoffset;
            $framedata=substr($framedata,$Xoffset);
            $i++;
            if ($i>100) break;
        }
        
        $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']=$this->conf['Id3v2FramesPos']+$this->conf['FramesLen'];
        fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']);
        $temp=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,4);
            if (bin2hex($temp)=='00000000'){
            $this->conf['OffPaddingPos']=$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
            $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=4;
            $ready=false;
                while ($ready===false){
                $temp=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,500);
                $ready=strpos($temp,chr(255));
                if ($ready===false)$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=500;
                else $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=$ready;
                }
            $this->conf['OffPaddingLen']=$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']-$this->conf['OffPaddingPos'];
            }
        $this->conf['OffpaddingBreak']=$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
        }
    }

    function ProcesMpeg(){
    fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['OffpaddingBreak']);
    $this->conf['tempHeader']=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,4);
    $ready=false;
    $y=0;
    $i=0;
    $x=0;
        while($ready==false){
            if($this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']>=$this->conf['FileSize']) $i=50;
            if ($this->MpegGoodHeader($this->conf['tempHeader'])==true){
            $this->mpegInfo=$this->ReadMpegHeader($this->conf['tempHeader']);
                $HasXing=false;
                $HasVbri=false;
                if ($y<=2){
                $temp=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,36);
                $HasXing=strpos($temp,"Xing");
                $HasVbri=strpos($temp,"VBRI");
                }
                if ($HasXing!==false || $HasVbri!==false){
                $ready=true;
                break;
                }
                elseif ($this->mpegInfo['ThisFramelen']>0){
                    if ($this->jumpMpegHeader($this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'],$this->mpegInfo['ThisFramelen'])){
                    $ready=true;
                    break;
                    } 
                    else{
                    $i++;
                    $this->LookforMpegHeader();
                    }
                }
                else{
                $i++;
                $this->LookforMpegHeader();
                }
            $y++;   
            }
            else{
            $i++;
            $this->LookforMpegHeader();
            }
            if ($i>=50){
            break;
            }
        }
        if ($ready){
        $this->conf['OffFileLen']=$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']-$this->conf['OffpaddingBreak'];
        $this->ReadMoreMpegHeader($this->conf['tempHeader']);
        $this->Getid3v1();
        $this->GetVbr();
        $this->GetPlayTime();
        }
        else{
        $this->conf['FileIdentifier']="MaybeNoMP3file";
        }
    }

    function Getid3v1(){
        fseek($this->TargetSrcFile, -128, SEEK_END);
        $id3v1tag = fread($this->TargetSrcFile, 128);
        $id3v1name    = trim(substr($id3v1tag,  0, 3));
        if ($id3v1name=="TAG" || $id3v1name=="ID3"){
        $this->id3v1Info['exist']=1;
        $this->id3v1Info['title']   = trim(substr($id3v1tag,  3, 30));
        $this->id3v1Info['artist']  = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 33, 30));
        $this->id3v1Info['album']   = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 63, 30));
        $this->id3v1Info['year']    = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 93,  4));
        $id3v1com = substr($id3v1tag, 97, 30);
            if ((substr($id3v1com , 28, 1) === chr(0)) && (substr($id3v1com , 29, 1) !== chr(0))) {
                $this->id3v1Info['track'] = ord(substr($id3v1com , 29, 1));
                $id3v1com  = substr($id3v1com , 0, 28);
            }
        $id3v1genre = ord(substr($id3v1tag, 127, 1));   
        $this->id3v1Info['comment'] = trim($id3v1com );
        $this->id3v1Info['genreID'] = $id3v1genre;
        $this->id3v1Info['genre'] = $this->GetGenre($id3v1genre);
        }
        else{
        $this->id3v1Info['exist']=0;
        return false;
        }
    }

    function GetPlayTime(){
        $this->mpegInfo['PlaySeconds']=($this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']*8)/($this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']*1000);
        $temptime=$this->mpegInfo['PlaySeconds'];
        $horas=floor($temptime/3600);
        $h=" ";$m="";$s="";
        if ($horas<10) $h=0;
        $temptime-=(3600*$horas);
        $minutos=floor($temptime/60);
        if ($minutos<10) $m=0;
        $temptime-=(60*$minutos);
        $segundos=floor($temptime);
        if ($segundos<10) $s=0;
        $this->mpegInfo['PlayTime']=sprintf($h."%d:".$m."%d:".$s."%d",$horas,$minutos,$segundos);
    }

    function GetVbr(){
        if ($this->mpegInfo['AudioVersion'] == 'MPEG1') {
            if ($this->mpegInfo['ChannelMode'] == 'Single channel') $VBRidOffset = 17; 
            else $VBRidOffset = 32; 
        } else { // 2 or 2.5
            if ($ChannelMode == 'Single channel') $VBRidOffset = 9;  
            else $VBRidOffset = 17; 
        }
    fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+4+$VBRidOffset);
    $vbrMethod = fread($this->TargetSrcFile, 4);
        if ($vbrMethod=='Xing'){
        $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']=$vbrMethod;
        $vbrFlags = fread($this->TargetSrcFile, 4);
        $vbrByte4 = $this->myStrBin2Bin(substr($vbrFlags,3,1));
        $vbr['frames']    = substr($vbrByte4, 4, 1);
        $vbr['bytes']     = substr($vbrByte4, 5, 1);
        $vbr['toc']       = substr($vbrByte4, 6, 1);
        $vbr['vbr_scale'] = substr($vbrByte4, 7, 1);
        $vbrAudio=fread($this->TargetSrcFile, 8);
        
            $uno=$this->myBigEndian2Int(substr($vbrAudio,0,4));
            $dos=$this->myBigEndian2Int(substr($vbrAudio,4,4));
            
            if ($uno>0 && $dos>0){
                if ($dos>$uno){
                //echo "vbr dos mayor";
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$dos;
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioFrames']=$uno;
                }
                else{
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$uno;
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioFrames']=$dos;
                }
                if (($this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes'])>$this->conf['FileSize']){
                $this->mpegInfo['LostAudio']=round((($this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']/$this->conf['FileSize'])*100)-100);
                if ($this->mpegInfo['LostAudio']>10){
                $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']='VeryBadXing';
                $this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']=$this->mpegInfo['Bitrate'];
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$this->conf['FileSize']-($this->id3v1Info['exist']*128)-$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
                $this->conf['FileIdentifier'] = 'MaybeNoID3file';
                }
                }
            
                
            }
            else{
            $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']='BadXing';
            $this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']=$this->mpegInfo['Bitrate'];
            $AudioBytes=$this->conf['FileSize']-($this->id3v1Info['exist']*128)-$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
                if ($dos>(($AudioBytes/3)*2)){
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$dos;
                }
                else{
                $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$AudioBytes;
                }
            }
        }
        elseif ($vbrMethod=='VBRI'){
        $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']=$vbrMethod;
        }
        else{
        $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']='CBR';
        $this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']=$this->mpegInfo['Bitrate'];
        $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$this->conf['FileSize']-($this->id3v1Info['exist']*128)-$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
        if($this->mpegInfo['MaybeVbr']==1){
        $this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']='UnkVBR';
        $this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']=$this->CalculateVbr($this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'],$this->mpegInfo['ThisFramelen']);
        $this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']=$this->conf['FileSize']-($this->id3v1Info['exist']*128)-$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos'];
        }
        }
        
        //if ($vbrMethod=='Xing' || $vbrMethod=='VBRI'){
        if ($this->mpegInfo['vbrMethod']=='Xing'){
            $this->mpegInfo['AudioFrames']--; // don't count the Xing / VBRI frame
            $coe=0;
            if ($this->mpegInfo['AudioVersion']=="MPEG1" && $this->mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']=="LayerI"){$coe=384;}
            elseif (($this->mpegInfo['AudioVersion']=="MPEG2" || $this->mpegInfo['AudioVersion']=="MPEG2.5") && $this->mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']=="LayerIII"){$coe=576;}
            else{$coe=1152;}
            if ($coe!=0){
            $VBRBitrate=((($this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']/$this->mpegInfo['AudioFrames']) * 8) * (($this->mpegInfo['SamplingRate'] / $coe)) / 1000);
        //echo "VBRBitrate=(((".$this->mpegInfo['AudioBytes']."/".$this->mpegInfo['AudioFrames'].") * 8) * ((".$this->mpegInfo['SamplingRate']." / ".$coe.")) / 1000)=".$VBRBitrate;
    
            $this->mpegInfo['Bitrate']=round($VBRBitrate);
            $this->mpegInfo['BitrateDec']=$VBRBitrate;
            }
        }
    
    }


    function ReadMoreMpegHeader($MpegHeader){
    $MpegHeader=substr($this->myStrBin2Bin($MpegHeader),24);
    $ChannelMode =substr($MpegHeader,0,2);
    $ModeExten   =substr($MpegHeader,2,2);
    $Copyright   =substr($MpegHeader,4,1);
    $Original    =substr($MpegHeader,5,1);
    $Emphasis    =substr($MpegHeader,6,2);
    $this->mpegInfo['ChannelMode']=$this->ChannelMode[$ChannelMode];
    if ($this->mpegInfo['ChannelMode']=='Joint stereo'){
        if($this->mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']=='LayerIII'){
        $this->mpegInfo['IntensityMSstereo']=$this->Intensity['IntensityMSstereo'][$ModeExten];
        }
        else{
        $this->mpegInfo['Band']=$SubbandsAR['Band'][$ModeExten];
        }
    }
    $this->mpegInfo['Copyright']=(int)$Copyright;
    $this->mpegInfo['Original']=(int)$Original;
    $this->mpegInfo['Emphasis']=$this->Emphasis[$Emphasis];
    }
    
    function CalculateVbr($pos,$framelen){
    $index=0;
    $jumps=30;
        while($index<$jumps){
        $pos=$pos+$framelen;
        if ($framelen==0)break;
        fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$pos);
        $tempHeader=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,4);
            if ($this->MpegGoodHeader($tempHeader)==true){
            $ff=array();
            $mpegInfo=$this->ReadMpegHeader($tempHeader);
                if (isset($mpegInfo['ThisFramelen'])){
                $framelen=$mpegInfo['ThisFramelen'];
                $ff[$index]['framelen']=$framelen;
                $ff[$index]['bitrate']=$mpegInfo['Bitrate'];
                }
                else{
                break;
                }
            }
            else{
            break;
            }
        $index++;
        }
    
    krsort($ff);    
    $i=0;
    $tt=0;
    while (list($k,$v)=each($ff)){
    $tt+=$v['framelen'];
    if ($i>20)break;
    $i++;
    }
    reset($ff);
    $i=0;
    $xx=0;
    while (list($k,$v)=each($ff)){
    $xx+=($v['framelen']/$tt)*$v['bitrate'];
    if ($i>20)break;
    $i++;
    }
    unset($this->mpegInfo['MaybeVbr']); 
    return $xx;
    }


    function jumpMpegHeader($pos,$framelen){
    $index=0;
        while($index<$this->jumps){
        $pos=$pos+$framelen;
        if ($framelen==0)break;
        fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$pos);
        $tempHeader=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,4);
            if ($this->MpegGoodHeader($tempHeader)==true){
            $mpegInfo=$this->ReadMpegHeader($tempHeader);
                if (isset($mpegInfo['ThisFramelen'])){
                $prevframelen=$framelen;
                $framelen=$mpegInfo['ThisFramelen'];
                    if ($framelen>$prevframelen+2 || $framelen<$prevframelen-2){
                    $this->mpegInfo['MaybeVbr']=1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                break;
                }
            }
            else{
            break;
            }
        $index++;
        }
        if ($index==$this->jumps)   return true;
        else return false;
    }


    function LookforMpegHeader(){
    $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=1;
    fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']);
    $ready=false;
    while ($ready==false){
    if($this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']>=$this->conf['FileSize']) break;
        $temp=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,1000);
        while (strlen($temp)>0){
            $x=strpos($temp,chr(255));
            if ($x===false){
            $FileOffsetLen+=1000;
            $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=1000;
            break;
            }
            else{
            $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=$x;
                while($ready==false){
                fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']);
                $temp2=hexdec(bin2hex(fread($this->TargetSrcFile,20)));
                    if ($temp2!=-1){
                    $ready=true;
                    }
                    else{
                    $this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']+=20;
                    }
                }
            fseek($this->TargetSrcFile,$this->conf['MpegHeaderPos']);
            $this->conf['tempHeader']=fread($this->TargetSrcFile,4);
            break;
            }
        }
    }
    }

    function ReadMpegHeader($MpegHeader){
    $HeaderBits=$this->myStrBin2Bin($MpegHeader);
    $BadSamplingRate=false;
    $mpegInfo=array();
    $mpegInfo['AudioVersion']=$this->LookAudioVersion[substr($HeaderBits,11,2)];
        if ($mpegInfo['AudioVersion']=='Reserved'){
        $mpegInfo['ThisFramelen']=0;
        }
        else{
        $mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']=$this->LookLayerDescrip[substr($HeaderBits,13,2)];
        $mpegInfo['ProtecBit']=(int)substr($HeaderBits,15,1);
        $mpegInfo['Bitrate']=$this->LookBitrateValues[$mpegInfo['AudioVersion']][$mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']][$this->LookBitrateIndex[substr($HeaderBits,16,4)]];
        $mpegInfo['SamplingRate']=$this->LookSamplingRate[$mpegInfo['AudioVersion']][substr($HeaderBits,20,2)];
            if ($mpegInfo['SamplingRate']=='Reserved'){
            $mpegInfo['ThisFramelen']=0;
            }else{
            $mpegInfo['PaddingBit']=(int)substr($HeaderBits,22,1);
            $coef=$this->LookFrameLen[$mpegInfo['AudioVersion']][$mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']]['coef'];
            $slotlen=$this->LookFrameLen[$mpegInfo['AudioVersion']][$mpegInfo['LayerDescrip']]['slotlen'];
            $FrameLengthInBytes = ($coef * $mpegInfo['Bitrate'] * 1000 / $mpegInfo['SamplingRate'] + $mpegInfo['PaddingBit']) * $slotlen;
            $mpegInfo['ThisFramelen']=floor($FrameLengthInBytes);
            }
        }
    return $mpegInfo;
    }

    function ShowInfo(){
        if (1==1){
        while (list($k,$v)=each($this->id3v2Info)){
            for($i=0;$i<count($v['info']);$i++){
            if ($k=="NCON" || $k=="GEOB" || $k=="APIC" || $k=="PIC"){
            $this->id3v2Info[$k]['info'][$i]['Value']="BetterNotShowIt";
            }
            else{
            $this->id3v2Info[$k]['info'][$i]['Value']=htmlspecialchars($this->id3v2Info[$k]['info'][$i]['Value']);
            }
            }
        }
        }
        $this->myPrint($this->conf,'red');
        $this->myPrint($this->id3v2Info,'green');
        $this->myPrint($this->mpegInfo,'blue');
        $this->myprint($this->id3v1Info,'orange');
    }
    
    function GetInfo($TargetNamFile){
        if ($this->OpenFile($TargetNamFile)){
        $this->ProcesId3v2();
        $this->ProcesMpeg();
        $this->CloseFile();
        }
    }
}//end class
?>
```

```
$sFullFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $TrackUrl;   

include ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/muz/id3v2.class.php';
$audio = new id3v2( );
$audio->GetInfo( $sFullFileName );
$id3v1 = $audio->id3v1Info;
$mpeg = $audio->mpegInfo;

$muz_beats = $parse->remove( $mpeg['Bitrate'] );
$muz_ggc = $parse->remove( $mpeg['SamplingRate'] );
$muz_lenght = $parse->remove( $mpeg['PlayTime'] );
$muz_razmer = @filesize( $sFullFileName );
$muz_search = $_POST['tags'] . " - " . $title;
```

Этим кодом получаю битрейт, размер и тп.

По аналогии пробовал писать так:

```
$muz_title = $parse->remove( $mpeg['title'] );
$muz_artist = $parse->remove( $mpeg['artist'] );
```

не читает ничего

Comment: Я надеюсь вы несерьёзно это полагаете, что люди будут смотреть весь этот код?))

Comment: А вдруг кто поможет. Весь код может пригодится. Обрезать я не знаю чего

Comment: Вы предоставили километровый не читаемый код. Если хотите, чтобы Вам помогли, то я думаю, что вам всё же следует сократить количество кода. А вообще, я бы советовал Вам всё же обратить внимание на качество вашего кода. У вас отсутствует нормальное форматирование, куча лишнего кода (не считая проверку на true или false). Нарушены правила именования переменных, функций. Километровые функции, уродливые свитчи.

Comment: @NaClnik да всё нормально, это не его код :)

Comment: Это не мой код, я сайт уже купил с этим, теперь разбираюсь. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Выбросьте вы это чудо. И нагуглите что-то более свежее, готовое и документированное. Что-нибудь вроде `composer require wapmorgan/mp3info`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть на строки

```
$this->id3v1Info['exist'] = 1;
$this->id3v1Info['title'] = trim(substr($id3v1tag,  3, 30));
$this->id3v1Info['artist'] = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 33, 30));
$this->id3v1Info['album'] = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 63, 30));
$this->id3v1Info['year'] = trim(substr($id3v1tag, 93,  4));
```

то получается, что информация содержится в массиве `$this->id3v1Info` и достать можно вроде так:

```
$id3v1 = $audio->id3v1Info;
$title = $id3v1['title'];
$artist = $id3v1['artist'];
```

Comment: А говорил, что не будут смотреть)

Comment: @vp_arth А я не смотрел весь код :)  Только когда добавили дополнение сделал ctrl+f :)

Comment: А из `id3v2` ни как не получить? Только `id3v1`. В `id3v1` не всегда теги прописаны

Comment: @steep вы знаете, на столько большой код, что я не горю желанием в нём разбираться)) Чисто если искать слова `title` и `artist` - то они лежат там где я написал, а id3v2 вроде это класс....... или вы имели в виду `id3v2Info` ? по коду я не вижу что туда кладётся....не понимаю